# Grid Column not resizing on rotate

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am developping a WP7 application. On the mainpage I have a ListBox. Each item contains a StackPanel and a Button. The size of the items IN the StackPanel is varying and the width of the Button is always 75px. I want the width of the part of the Stackpanel to be always 80% of the screenwidth. I use following DataTemplate for the ListBox:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,17" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemDescription}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemLocation}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemDate}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,6,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="deleteTaskButton" Width="75" Height="75" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,-18,0,0" Click="DeleteTaskButtonClick">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=RemindersListBox, Path=DataContext.ImgSource}" Height="48" Width="48" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

I used the solution from this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140608/how-to-change-stackpanel-width-on-rotate). But the Grid is not resizing. How can I achieve to get the first column of the Grid to be 80% of the width, both in Landscape and Portrait mode? This has got me busy for hours already...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that listboxitem is not stretched to whole width. Use this approach to handle this: [WP7 list width issue when orientation changs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8571854/820813)

Answer (score 2):

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Should give you an 80/20 split on column sizes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I was also thinking in that direction and I tried your solution but this doesn't work either.. :S

Comment: In combination with the answer of Ku6opr, this works like a charm. Only, his given solution was key! :)